# FileUploader uploads file to backend even when it is not needed

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I can be wrong, but looking at how FileUploader from https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader
behaves really makes me puzzled.

The control was defined like this:

```
<u:FileUploader id="fileUploader"
                uploadStart="onBedfileUploadStart"
                uploadOnChange="true"
                uploadComplete="onBedfileUploadFinish"
                typeMissmatch="handleTypeMissmatch"
                style="Emphasized"
                fileType="bed"
                value="{labtestEditorModel>BED_FILE_NAME}"
                placeholder="{i18n>common.UploadFile}">
</u:FileUploader>
```

What I see when uploading the page is that a request is sent to the backend.
[image]

When I do have a real deployed app on my remote host, some heavy files will be uploaded pretty slow (like minutes, etc.)

I have a callback handler `onBedfileUploadFinish` which is triggered only when upload is finished. The issue however is that for remote host it takes quite some time because upload do upload file to somewhere. Only then `onBedfileUploadFinish` is triggered and I access the file from the browser by:

```
function onBedfileUploadFinish(oEvent) {
      const source = oEvent.getSource();
      const domRef = source.getFocusDomRef();
      const file = domRef.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      const localModel = this.getView().getModel('localModel');

      reader.onloadend = function () {
        localModel.setProperty('/bedFileContent', reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
```

The point is: I never wanted my data to be uploaded to remote server. I don't specify a param `uploadUrl` , hence I expect no requests in my network tab at all. I just want to preload data locally and send it over by need. How do I achieve that?

I was thinking of smth like using only `change` event instead:

```
<u:FileUploader id="fileUploader"
                change="onBedfileUploadFinish"
                typeMissmatch="handleTypeMissmatch"
                style="Emphasized"
                fileType="bed"
                value="{labtestEditorModel>BED_FILE_NAME}"
                placeholder="{i18n>common.UploadFile}">
</u:FileUploader>
```

Would that be correct?

Comment: uploadOnChange is set to true. This is not the default btw.

Comment: Yes, this I've also removed in my latest attempt